# C++ pass function pointer in function template

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I'm trying to pass a function pointer in a template, to then use it in asm code:

```
template <auto T>
_declspec(naked) void Test()
{
    __asm
    {
        lea eax, T
        jmp [eax]
    }
}

int main()
{
    Test<MessageBoxA>();
    Test<Sleep>();
}
```

I know the naked function will crash when executed but I've simplified the code to show only what I'm trying to achieve.

The problem with this code is that once compiled, if you look at the assembly code in a disassembler, it will look like this:

```
lea eax, 0
jmp [eax]
```

It is storing 0 in eax. Instead, it should store the `MessageBoxA` address (and `Sleep` in another function) in eax.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or the compiler is failing.

Comment: `&MessageBoxA` ?

Comment: @Aganju same output.

Comment: You tagged this [compiler-errors], but you're saying it actually does compile, just not to the asm you want. If there actually is an error message, edit your question.

Comment: Did you look at compiler asm output on https://godbolt.org/, or in a linked executable?  If only disassembly of a `.obj`, the `0` might just be a placeholder to be filled in by the linker.

Comment: @PeterCordes I looked the executable in both in IDA static disassembler and debugger.

Comment: Unfortunately templates and inline assembly don't mix well.

Comment: I am siding with @oisyn . A couple of years ago there was another MSVC related question about inline and templates and pretty sure the conclusion was that there were problems with the combination. After searching I can't find it though.

Comment: note: using `__declspec(naked)` is not recommended for any method you're calling from a high level language. That's intended to be used for calls from assembly realistically. It basically does *no calling convention* so it throws caution to the wind and can mess everything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an assembly expert, but creating a `static constexpr void*` set to the non-type template parameter value seems to do the trick:

```
template <auto T>
__declspec(naked) void Test()
{
    static constexpr void* fptr = T;
    
    __asm 
    {
        lea eax, fptr
        jmp [eax]
    }
}

const void sleep()
{
}

int main()
{
    Test<(&sleep)>();
    return 0;
}
```

generates

```
lea     eax, OFFSET void * `void Test<&void sleep(void)>(void)'::`2'::fptr
jmp     SHORT DWORD PTR [eax]
```

The example can be played with on compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/f1d7daa49